# Resume pg_restore after network failure

Tags: postgresql, networking, restore, database-restore, pg-restore

If a network failure causes a `pg_restore` process to exit, is it possible to resume the restore?

Answer (score 3):

According to [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4EE944C0.4080404@ringerc.id.au) there is no easy way to resume your `pg_restore`.

Answer (score 0):

If restarting the restore freshly with `--clean` (! will delete data on the target) is not an option... well restarting the restore would be possible, but you will have a lot of errors (for things already created like constraints/indicies). So using `--verbose` and capturing the logs with `2>output.txt` makes sense so you can (manually) check if something went wrong.

Depending on the size of the restored database and the number of objects to restore that might be very time consuming and of course error prone!